# How to delete java project from eclipse without affecting subversion?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I want to delete project that was checked-out using 'subclipse' from the eclipse without affecting subversion. When I click on "Delete" option and then "preview", it shows two check boxes which are

- Delete 'project_name' - c:\local
- Java EE Server Cleanup (Remove deleted project from server)

What does the second "Java EE Server Cleanup (Remove deleted project from server)" mean?

Will deleting the project checked out from eclipse affect subversion repository?

Comment: Checking this option will remove the deployed application on your local server (tomcat, jetty, or whatever). Nothing will occur on your SVN repository =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you will delete the deployed project from your (local) development server, like Tomcat or Glassfish.

Deleting a project in eclipse will never touch subversion unless you take specific actions using the subversion plugins.